# Pointer events firing at the wrong time

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am running into a problem where mousing over one object in my scene causes all of the `onPointerOver` listeners in the scene to fire at once, sometimes randomly. I think this is because of the way that I am adding components to the scene, but I'm not sure.

What could be causing this behavior? Here is an example of my code for reference.

I have a `SampleObject` constructor like this, which takes an `image` path and a `mouseOver` function as props:

```
const SampleObject = ({ image, mouseOver }) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const texture = useLoader(TextureLoader, image);
    return (<mesh ref={ref} onMouseOver={mouseOver}>
       <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" />
       <meshPhongMaterial attach="material" map={texture}/>
    </mesh>)
}
export default React.memo(SampleObject);
```

And in the render, I am loading it using `Suspense` because it involves loading an image. The `onPointerOver` listener updates a state:

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
    <SampleObject image={ images(`./image.png`).default } onPointerOver={() => {  setMiscState(true)  }} />
    <SampleObject image={ images(`./image.png`).default } onPointerOver={() => {  setMiscState(false)  }} />
</Suspense>
```

Therefore, when the state changes, all of these `SampleObject` components re-render. Is that what's causing the `onPointerOver` events to fire at the wrong times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs in an outdated version of `react-three-fiber`. Update the package to fix it.

Otherwise, to prevent this problem, enclose each object in a separate `Suspense` wrapper:

```
[

<Suspense key='suspense1' fallback={null}>
    <SampleObject image={ images(`./image.png`).default } onPointerOver={() => {  setMiscState(true)  }} />
</Suspense>,

<Suspense key='suspense2' fallback={null}>
    <SampleObject image={ images(`./image.png`).default } onPointerOver={() => {  setMiscState(false)  }} />
</Suspense>

]
```